# Escaping both forward slash and back slash with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following string: `/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt`

I wish to use `sed` to substitute `/` for `\/` - for example:

```
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

So I issue:

```
echo "/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt" | sed "s/\//\\\\//g"
```

Although it returns:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

I am escaping the forward slash and backslash - so not sure where I have gone wrong here

Comment: Do you want to substitute `/` for `\/` (so replace all `\/` with `/`) or do you want to substitute `\/` for `/` (replace all `/` with `\/`)?

Comment: @James you could use different delimiter in sed command, like   sed 's:something:toSomethingElse:'

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to escape (with backslash `\`) all substituted slashes `/` and all backslashes `\` separately, so:

```
$ echo "/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

but that's rather unreadable.

However, `sed` allows to use almost any character as a separator instead of `/`, this is especially useful when one wants to substitute slash `/` itself, as in your case, so using for example semicolon `;` as separator the command would become simpler:

```
echo "/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt" | sed 's;/;\\/;g'
```

---

**Other cases:**

- If one wants to stick with slash as a separator and use double quotes then all escaped backslashes have to be escaped one more time to preserve their literal values:

  ```
  echo "/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt" | sed "s/\//\\\\\//g"
  ```
- if one doesn't want quotes at all then yet another backslash is needed:

  ```
  echo "/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt" | sed s/\\//\\\\\\//g
  ```

Comment: Thanks I also noticed you are using single quotes - since I presume double quotes would not preserve the literal value of the '\' character.

Comment: @James yes, everything inside single quotes is treated literally by shell and as that passed to `sed`. Inside double quotes some characters are expanded, and even whole expressions could be evaluated by shell.

Comment: @James I added examples with different quotation to the answer, it may be useful.

Comment: Thanks! I realised that having `/` is a bad idea when your data contains `/` - simple, but subtle. Often, you need to take a step back and think about the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Or, if the value is in a (bash) shell variable:

```
var=/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt
$ echo "${var//\//\\\/}"
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

The first `//` start [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), saying to replace *all* matches with the replacement. The next `\/` is the escaped `/` to match, and the `\\\/` is an escaped `\` followed by an escaped `/` as the replacement.

Comment: Other forms of quoting (beside backslash) may be used. Try `echo "${var//'/'/'\/'}"` (since bash 4.3)

Answer (score 3):

The final solution will be this one:

```
$ sed 's:/:\\/:g'  <<<"$str"
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

---

But to explain how to get there:
Yes, you were missing one backslash:

```
$ str='/tmp/test/folder1/test.txt'
$ sed "s/\//\\\\\//g" <<<"$str"
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

I hope that one space will make it clear:

```
$ sed "s/\//\\\\ \//g"  <<<"$str"
\ /tmp\ /test\ /folder1\ /test.txt
```

But, if you were to change the sed delimiter to `:` (for example):

```
$  sed "s:\/:\\\\\/:g"  <<<"$str"
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

But that is not strictly correct as the (now not special) `/` does not need scaping:

```
$ sed "s:/:\\\\/:g"  <<<"$str"
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

And, if you were to use single quotes instead of double quotes the shell will not change double `\\` to one, so less `\` will be correct:

```
$ sed 's:/:\\/:g'  <<<"$str"
\/tmp\/test\/folder1\/test.txt
```

Which is quite cleaner.